# How to store scope_identity value to a variable using datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
objcon.GetReader(" insert into product(name,price)Values('" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_price.Text + "') select scope_identity() ");

if (objcon.dr.Read())
{
    var id = objcon.dr[0].ToString();
}

objcon.dr.Close();
```

I want to store the `scope_identity` value into a variable. The above code is working. But I am not getting the value in variable id. Can someone please help?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Also, you should **not** use a `IDataReader` for running `INSERT` operations - only for selects. If you want to insert, use `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @marc_s If Anju wants to use a select to get identity value, the `NonQuery` would not work. `ExecuteScalar` would be the way to go in that particular case

Comment: @bradbury9: true - good point. But the data reader is definitely the wrong approach ...

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I last worked directly with ADO.Net, so this might not be 100% accurate.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    insert into product(name,price) Values(@name, @price);
    select scope_identity();", objCon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToInt32(txt_price.Text));
var newId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

The SqlCommand object is ideal for performing queries that returns nothing, or a single value

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of affected rows. F.ex. how many row was actually updated, inserted, or deleted (note: triggers can affect this value)

`ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column of the first row, in the result, and ignores the rest. It's perfect to retrieving a newly inserted ID or a count, or a sum, etc. The returned type is object, but can be cast to the expected type.